# What is cause of PyQt4/Qt abort trap when calling CGPathAddArc?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to Mavericks, with PyQt 4.10.4, Qt 4.8.5, python 2.7.5, I was trying to rebuild a PyQt application and encountered the following abort trap:

```
Assertion failed: (CGFloatIsValid(x) && CGFloatIsValid(y)), function void CGPathAddArc(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, bool), file Paths/CGPath.cc, line 279.
Abort trap: 6
```

This is [issue](https://github.com/ilastik/ilastik/issues/776) reflects that CGPathAddArc on Mavericks rejects NaN values from Qt (which on Snow Leopard it used to tolerate/warn about). There is a [patch](https://github.com/chaubold/buildem/commit/ef1bf095794bbc3717659225e48e0a21ff34b92d) that looks good, but applying it requires rebuilding Qt and PyQt, and I wasn't able to get it to work for me.

faultHandler gives no details, and runsnake yields no output since the app terminates abnormally.

It's obviously a UI element, but how do I find which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Culprit was a QGraphicsEllipseItem() declared with no parameters. [Qt 4.8 documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsellipseitem.html#dtor.QGraphicsEllipseItem) suggests no params is a valid constructor, but apparently in Mavericks this is not the case.

Declaring the QGraphicsEllipseItem with dummy x and y parameters resolved the issue.